# How can I create FlurryAgent.logEvent in onCreate() activity method?

Tags: android, flurry

The documentation says, that

> onStartSession should be called from within the onStart method of the activity in question.

How can I logEvents() from *onCreate()* method in this case?
Will library works fine if I'll put onStartSession() to *onCreate()* method
or there is another way for resolving my question?

**UPDATE**

Inside `onCreate()` I am starting AsyncTask with web-request to the server so in `onPreExecute()` I want to put `FlurryAgent.logEvent`.

Comment: create a queue of events for anything that happens before onStartSession is called. As soon as that is called, loop through your queue and call all of the logging.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend calling `FlurryAgent.onStartSession()` from `onCreate()`, due to the nature of the Activity lifecycle. If a user were to navigate away from an Activity for a while (take a call, text message, etc) and then return, `onStart()` will be called but not `onCreate()`. If don't call `onStartSession()` from `onStart()`, you wouldn't be tracking this new session, and you might run into errors with events that occur inside your Activity.

What's the nature of the events you want to track inside `onCreate()`? Usually you want to set up the UI and any other components of the Activity in this method but there won't be user interaction at this point, so I would think you could track the state of the Activity after `onStart()` without a lot of refactoring.

(disclaimer: I work on the Android SDK at Flurry)